# What is the easiest way to update Opera browser on Ubuntu 18?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, opera

How can I update Opera browser on Ubuntu 18?
when I do `sudo apt-get upgrade opera` I face with this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 opera : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.16) but it is not installable
         Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.15) but it is not installable
         Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good but it is not installable
 opera-stable : Conflicts: opera but 12.16.1860 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

so how can I update it? I have Opera Version:56.0.3051.104.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @karel I want to update it not install it. doesn't that  make any difference? sorry if I'm a new be.

Comment: `sudo snap refresh opera` if the opera snap package is already installed.